# Is it possible to have an ovalshape, withevents, declared in an object VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oop, object, events, event-handling

Is it possible to have an ovalshape, withevents, declared in an object and then use that ovalshape for an event handler inside my Form1 class?

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public WithEvents Oval As New OvalShape
    Public WithEvents Label As New Label
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Dim MyObject As New MyClass  
    Private Sub Oval_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyObject.Oval.DoubleClick
        ''' Do something here
    End Sub
```

Comment: I must be missing some code because it gives me an error message "Handles in classes must specify WithEvent variables, MyBase, MyClass or Me qualified with a single identifier."

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The event handlers and the objects whose events are handled must be in the same class.

So put the eventhandler in `MyClass` and use an instance of that class:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public WithEvents Oval As New OvalShape
    Public WithEvents Label As New Label

    Private Sub Oval_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Oval.DoubleClick
        ''' Do something here
    End Sub
End Class
```

And if you intend to actually respond to the Double Click, you have to display the Oval and Label, so that the user can see it and click it. For that again you have to take other steps. Your approach is not at all suitable to achieve what your code tells us.

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution to the code above, that was just an example. I was asking if there is a way to do this

Comment: No there's no way you can handle events of objects of one class from another.